How to perform a join_asof in Polars looking only backward and matching on specific conditions?
I'm trying to perform a join_asof in Polars where it only looks backward in time, ignoring matches on the same row. Specifically, I want it to find the last row where the Team and Field match exactly, but only if the Wk value is less than the current row's Wk.
The goal is to get the last GeneralLambda for recent games, either "Away" or "Home," excluding the current game. I thought the best way to do this would be with a join_asof, but I'm struggling with how to make it only consider past rows and match on both Team and Field.
Here is an example DataFrame to illustrate:



Season
Wk
Team
Field
GeneralLambda




2024
25
TeamA
Away
2.123456


2024
25
TeamB
Home
1.234567


2024
25
TeamC
Away
0.987654


2024
25
TeamD
Home
1.345678


2024
25
TeamE
Away
1.456789


2024
26
TeamA
Home
1.234567


2024
26
TeamB
Away
1.345678


2024
26
TeamC
Home
0.876543


2024
26
TeamD
Away
1.456789


2024
26
TeamE
Home
1.567890


2024
27
TeamA
Away
2.278759


2024
27
TeamB
Away
1.103829


2024
27
TeamC
Home
0.992563


2024
27
TeamD
Home
1.089324


2024
27
TeamE
Home
1.074221



For each row, I need to join it with the last matching row where:

Team is the same,
Field is the same,
Wk is less than the current row’s Wk.

I hope the DataFrame looks like this:



Season
Wk
Team
Field
GeneralLambda
Prev_GeneralLambda




2024
25
TeamA
Away
2.123456
ALastAwayValue


2024
25
TeamB
Home
1.234567
BLastHomeValue


2024
25
TeamC
Away
0.987654
CLastAwayValue


2024
25
TeamD
Home
1.345678
DLastHomeValue


2024
25
TeamE
Away
1.456789
ELastAwayValue


2024
26
TeamA
Home
1.234567
ALastHomeValue


2024
26
TeamB
Away
1.345678
BLastAwayValue


2024
26
TeamC
Home
0.876543
CLastHomeValue


2024
26
TeamD
Away
1.456789
DLastAwayValue


2024
26
TeamE
Home
1.567890
ELastHomeValue


2024
27
TeamA
Away
2.278759
2.123456


2024
27
TeamB
Away
1.103829
1.345678


2024
27
TeamC
Home
0.992563
0.876543


2024
27
TeamD
Home
1.089324
1.345678


2024
27
TeamE
Home
1.074221
1.567890



Is there a way to do this in Polars?

As per the suggested duplicate: df.with_columns(pl.col('GeneralLambda').shift().over('Team', 'Field').alias('Prev_GeneralLambda')).

(
    df.sort("Wk")
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("GeneralLambda")
        .shift(1)
        .fill_null(pl.col("Team").str.tail(1) + "Last" + pl.col("Field") + "Value")
        .over("Team","Field")
        .alias("Prev_GeneralLambda")
    )
)

shape: (15, 6)
┌────────┬─────┬───────┬───────┬───────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ Season ┆ Wk  ┆ Team  ┆ Field ┆ GeneralLambda ┆ Prev_GeneralLambda │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---           ┆ ---                │
│ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str   ┆ f64           ┆ str                │
╞════════╪═════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 2024   ┆ 25  ┆ TeamA ┆ Away  ┆ 2.123456      ┆ ALastAwayValue     │
│ 2024   ┆ 25  ┆ TeamB ┆ Home  ┆ 1.234567      ┆ BLastHomeValue     │
│ 2024   ┆ 25  ┆ TeamC ┆ Away  ┆ 0.987654      ┆ CLastAwayValue     │
│ 2024   ┆ 25  ┆ TeamD ┆ Home  ┆ 1.345678      ┆ DLastHomeValue     │
│ 2024   ┆ 25  ┆ TeamE ┆ Away  ┆ 1.456789      ┆ ELastAwayValue     │
│ …      ┆ …   ┆ …     ┆ …     ┆ …             ┆ …                  │
│ 2024   ┆ 27  ┆ TeamA ┆ Away  ┆ 2.278759      ┆ 2.123456           │
│ 2024   ┆ 27  ┆ TeamB ┆ Away  ┆ 1.103829      ┆ 1.345678           │
│ 2024   ┆ 27  ┆ TeamC ┆ Home  ┆ 0.992563      ┆ 0.876543           │
│ 2024   ┆ 27  ┆ TeamD ┆ Home  ┆ 1.089324      ┆ 1.345678           │
│ 2024   ┆ 27  ┆ TeamE ┆ Home  ┆ 1.074221      ┆ 1.56789            │
└────────┴─────┴───────┴───────┴───────────────┴────────────────────┘

